# Lost rubymine local history

Tags: rubymine

I was using rubymine 2016.1
Then I updated to rubymine 2016.2

Now all my local history is gone.
Where does rubymine store local history. How can I retrieve my old local history with this new version?

Thanks in advance to any helpful jetbrainers out there.

Answer (score 0):

After some sleep. The answer became evident. Delete the new version of rubymine. Then reinstall the old version and restart. Restart because I was seeing some wierd Java errors. A bit of googling showed that what other people were doing was essentially restarting their macs. Just like windows. Everything works just fine after a restart. Hope this helps someone.